# Groovy 3 - ASTTransformation annotation segregated

Tags: java, groovy, annotations, groovy-3.0

I want that my custom annotation must be used in conjunction with Immutable annotation. I achieved this by the following code -

Annotation class -

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@Target([ElementType.TYPE])
@GroovyASTTransformationClass(classes = TestFactoryTransform)
@interface TestFactory {
}
```

Its transformation class -

```
@GroovyASTTransformation(phase = CompilePhase.SEMANTIC_ANALYSIS)
public class TestFactoryTransform implements ASTTransformation {

  @Override
  public void visit(ASTNode[] astNodes, SourceUnit sourceUnit) {
    ClassNode classNode = (ClassNode) astNodes[1]
    if (classNode.getAnnotations(ClassHelper.make(Immutable)).size() == 0) {
        // throw ERROR
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

I have a test case to verify -

```
@TestFactory
@Immutable
@AnnotationCollector
@interface SampleTestFactory {}

@SampleTestFactory
class Test1 {
  int f1
}

class TestFactoryTransformTest {

  @Test
  void testIntField() {
    ...
  }
}
```

this is working fine with groovy 2.

**BUT**, after upgrading groovy to 3.0.13. This test compilation is failing because `if` condition of TestFactoryTransform is true (Immutable annotation not found).

when I print the output of  `classNode.getAnnotations()` statement then with groovy 2, I am getting -

```
[
    org.codehaus.groovy.ast.AnnotationNode@16c0bc,
    org.codehaus.groovy.ast.AnnotationNode@16c0bc,
    org.codehaus.groovy.ast.AnnotationNode@16c0bc
]
```

But with groovy 3, I am getting

```
[
    org.codehaus.groovy.ast.AnnotationNode@390fbe99[@com.my.transform.TestFactory()],
    org.codehaus.groovy.ast.AnnotationNode@587db6e0[@groovy.transform.TupleConstructor(defaults: false)],
    org.codehaus.groovy.ast.AnnotationNode@5798d0f[@groovy.transform.ToString(includeSuperProperties: true, cache: true)],
    org.codehaus.groovy.ast.AnnotationNode@54f967a6[@groovy.transform.EqualsAndHashCode(cache: true)],
    org.codehaus.groovy.ast.AnnotationNode@7293bc6b[@groovy.transform.ImmutableBase()],
    org.codehaus.groovy.ast.AnnotationNode@735697ed[@groovy.transform.ImmutableOptions()],
    org.codehaus.groovy.ast.AnnotationNode@2818eebe[@groovy.transform.PropertyOptions(propertyHandler: groovy.transform.options.ImmutablePropertyHandler)],
    org.codehaus.groovy.ast.AnnotationNode@68c5d616[@groovy.transform.MapConstructor(noArg: true, includeSuperProperties: true, includeFields: true)], 
    org.codehaus.groovy.ast.AnnotationNode@24992745[@groovy.transform.KnownImmutable()]
]
```

Any idea, why I am getting immutable annotation segregated with its inner annotations? And what I can do to fix the issue.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken `@Immutable` is a singular annotation in Groovy 2.5.x, but it was broken into components with Groovy 3.x, and it is now just a meta annotation based on `@AnnotationCollector` as you can see in the [GroovyDoc](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/3.0.5/html/gapi/groovy/transform/Immutable.html).

I don't think that there is anything to fix, you just need to update your logic to also accept the new component annotations, probably `@ImmutableBase` and `@KnownImmutable`.